# Unison implement handler - "Request" not recognized

Tags: unison-lang

I was having fun trying out Unison lang.
Then I decided to update the language version as being very old.
It ended up with me deleting it entirely and re-installing from scratch due to weird issues.

After re-installing it seems it is not working as expected.

Starting `ucm` creating a new file and pasting what I found in the [official documentation](https://www.unison-lang.org/docs/language-reference/abilities-and-ability-handlers/#pattern-matching-on-ability-constructors:%7E:text=Pattern-,matching,-on%20ability%20constructors):

```
structural ability Abort2 where
  Abort2.abort : {Abort2} a

toDefault!.handler : '{g} a -> Request {Abort2} a ->{g} a
toDefault!.handler default = cases
  { a }          -> a
  { abort -> _ } -> !default
```

I have this error:

```
    I couldn't resolve any of these symbols:
    
        4 | toDefault!.handler : '{g} a -> Request {Abort2} a ->{g} a
    
    
    Symbol    Suggestions
              
    Request   No matches
```

It seems it cannot find the `Request`

am I doing something wrong?

Anyone know why is this happening?

Version used is:

```
$ ucm --version
ucm version: release/0.5.18 (built on 2024-02-27)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I couldn't resolve any of these symbols

This message indicates to me that you don’t have the Base library anywhere in your current namespace.

When you first start UCM with a fresh codebase, begin by creating a project structure with `project.create` at the UCM prompt. It will go download the Base library and drop you into a new project with a `lib` namespace that contains Base.